# How to configure sqlite column so that it can take any kind of values

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-insert

cur.execute("INSERT INTO taula (time, username, **tweet**, location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)" % (time.time(), username, tweet, location))

username , tweet and location are my values coming from twitter stream

Suppose my tweet contains -  "RT @Nicksnacs4u: 1964 Ford Galaxie Dealer Promotional Model Car // by Successionary"

I need to configure my tweet column so that it can take any kind of text whether it contains special character like **@Nicksnacs4u** or not. Currently it it failing because some tweets contain text like **#sometext , @username %, $.**

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using placeholders in the SQL statement instead of formatting them yourself.

```
cur.execute(
    'INSERT INTO taula(time, username, tweet, location) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
    (time.time(), username, tweet, location),
)
```

Please read https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html for more details.  By formatting your own SQL statements you are opening the door to some nasty SQL injection attacks.

[image: xkcd 327]

Comment: Thank you so much. Currently, SQL injection is not my concern but your answer solved my problem.